# Deserialize JSON Array to Object with private list property using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

A JSON string like:

```
[
  "a", "b", "c"
]
```

Would usually be deserialized to `List<String>`. But I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Foo {
  private List<String> theList;

  public Foo(List<String> theList) {
      this.theList = theList;
  }

  public String toString() {
      return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(theList);
  }

  // ... more methods
}
```

Now I want to deserialize the above JSON string into an object of class `Foo` like:

```
Foo foo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Foo.class);
```

How is that possible?

I've already tried to use `@JsonCreator` with the constructor but always get:

```
JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of ... out of START_ARRAY token
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jackson 2.4.3, this

```
@JsonCreator
public Foo(List<String> theList) {
    this.theList = theList;
}
...

String jsonString = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]";
Foo foo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Foo.class);
System.out.println(foo.getTheList());
```

works for me. It prints

```
[a, b, c]
```