# Jackson:UnrecognisedPropertyException

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following classes:

**LocationCustomDataItem.java**

```
public class LocationCustomDataItem {

private String attributeNumber;
private String attributeLabel;
private String attributeValue;

public LocationCustomDataItem() {

}

public LocationCustomDataItem(final String attributeNumber, final String attributeLabel, final String attributeValue) {
    this.attributeNumber = attributeNumber;
    this.attributeLabel = attributeLabel;
    this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
}
/**
 * @return the attributeNumber
 */
public String getAttributeNumber() {
    return attributeNumber;
}
/**
 * @param attributeNumber the attributeNumber to set
 */
public void setAttributeNumber(String attributeNumber) {
    this.attributeNumber = attributeNumber;
}
/**
 * @return the attributeLabel
 */
public String getAttributeLabel() {
    return attributeLabel;
}
/**
 * @param attributeLabel the attributeLabel to set
 */
public void setAttributeLabel(String attributeLabel) {
    this.attributeLabel = attributeLabel;
}
/**
 * @return the attributeValue
 */
public String getAttributeValue() {
    return attributeValue;
}
/**
 * @param attributeValue the attributeValue to set
 */
public void setAttributeValue(String attributeValue) {
    this.attributeValue = attributeValue;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, false);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE, false);
}
```

**LocationCustomDataAttributes.java**

```
public class LocationCustomDataAttributes {

private final List<LocationCustomDataItem> locationCustomDataItems;

public LocationCustomDataAttributes() {
    this.locationCustomDataItems = new ArrayList<>();
}

public LocationCustomDataAttributes(final List<LocationCustomDataItem> locationCustomDataItems) {
    this.locationCustomDataItems = locationCustomDataItems;
}

/**
 * @return unmodifiable locationCustomDataItems list
 */
public List<LocationCustomDataItem> getLocationCustomDataItems() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.locationCustomDataItems);
}

/**
 * Adds LocationCustoDataItem to internal collection
 * 
 * @param item LocationCustomDataItem to add to item list
 */
public void addItem(final LocationCustomDataItem item) {
    this.locationCustomDataItems.add(item);
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, false);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE, false);
}
```

and this test json:

```
{
   "locationCustomDataAttributes" : {
      "locationCustomDataItems" : [ {
         "attributeLabel" : "testLabel1",
         "attributeNumber" : "testNumber1",
         "attributeValue" : "testLabel1"
      }, {
         "attributeLabel" : "testLabel2",
         "attributeNumber" : "testNumber2",
         "attributeValue" : "testLabel2"
      } ]
   }
}
```

I'm trying to use an ObjectMapper to convert the json to the object, but it is throwing an unrecognisedPropertyException around "locationCustomDataAttributes":

**MapperTest.java**

```
@Test
public void test() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper om =new ObjectMapper();

    LocationCustomDataAttributes actual = om.readValue(json, LocationCustomDataAttributes.class);

    LocationCustomDataAttributes expected = new LocationCustomDataAttributes();
    expected.addItem(new LocationCustomDataItem("testNumber1", "testLabel1", "testValue1"));
    expected.addItem(new LocationCustomDataItem("testNumber2", "testLabel2", "testValue2"));

    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
}
```

error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "locationCustomDataAttributes" (class com.lmig.ci.fnol.transformer.domain.LocationCustomDataAttributes), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "locationCustomDataItems"])
 at [Source: {"locationCustomDataAttributes" : {"locationCustomDataItems" : [ {"attributeLabel" : "testLabel1","attributeNumber" : "testNumber1","attributeValue" : "testLabel1"},{"attributeLabel" : "testLabel2","attributeNumber" : "testNumber2","attributeValue" : "testLabel2"}]}}; line: 1, column: 36] (through reference chain: com.lmig.ci.fnol.transformer.domain.LocationCustomDataAttributes["locationCustomDataAttributes"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:833)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1096)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1467)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1445)
```

//etc...`

I don't ave a massive amount of experience working with Jackson directly so I haven't annotated the class itself yet, but from previous efforts(e.g. with Spring controllers) the conversion happens automatically without the need for annotations on the class. In this instance that doesn't look like the case, what am I missing from the class, or does the current class structure not lend itself to automatic conversion by Jackson for some reason?

Comment: Try adding a `LocationCustomDataAttributes#setLocationCustomDataItems(...)` method.  Jackson doesn't know it could use the `addItem(...)` method.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495261/deserialize-json-array-to-object-with-private-list-property-using-jackson) is probably the better approach since it doesn't expose a setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
om.readValue(json, LocationCustomDataAttributes.class)
```

This line asks to parse a `LocationCustomDataAttributes` object from the JSON document. But JSON actually contains a wrapper object with a property that can be parsed into a `LocationCustomDataAttributes` object. Solutions:

1. Create a reader for a wrapped object. E.g.

   ```
   ObjectReader reader = om
       .readerFor(LocationCustomDataAttributes.class)
       .withRootName("locationCustomDataAttributes");
   LocationCustomDataAttributes actual = reader.readValue(json);
   ```
2. Define a wrapper class

   ```
   class AttributesWrapper {
       private LocationCustomDataAttributes locationCustomDataAttributes;
       // add getters, setters, constructors etc
   }
   ```

   and then parse it:

   ```
   LocationCustomDataAttributes actual = om
       .readValue(json, AttributesWrapper.class)
       .getLocationCustomDataAttributes();
   ```